# Unable to run react native project due to react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: android, react-native, npm, react-navigation

I have added react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler. When I run the project using react-native run-android, I get the following error:

- What went wrong:

```
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GSTCalc\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
settings file 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Project\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 133.
```

```
Following is the content of my settings.gradle file:
```

```js
rootProject.name = 'GSTCalc'
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
include ':app'
```

I have tried to delete node-modules folder from my project folder. and run npm install. But all in vain. What else should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your gradle file.

Comment: Following are the contents of my settings.gradle file...
rootProject.name = 'Project'

include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
include ':app'

Comment: Add gradle to the bottom of question in Markdown using edit button. :)

Comment: Bottom left of your question. or use find word `edit` on your browser.

Comment: did you link react-native-gesture-handler package?

Comment: yes... I did link react-native-gesture-handler package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this same problem.

My initial line (the one with the error) was:

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
```

I changed it to :

```
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```

I rebuilt it and it works! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It works by adding this:

```js
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
```

Answer (score 0):

add kotlin version in `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
       ...
       kotlinVersion = "1.5.20"
       ...
    }
}
```